# I havent'got any SWF file but Getting popup message - This page requires AC_RunActiveContent.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, alert

I haven't got any  `.swf` file on my web page but getting popup message `This page requires AC_RunActiveContent.js`. And my web page not working. I'm using Jquery library, colorbox and responsiveSlide plugin. Can someone help me ?

[link my website](http://ikonmimarlik.com)

------ Edit - Solved

If you use some plugins on your browser you could get this error. Because some plugins need this file. I upload this JS file into root directory on FTP and problem is solved.

Comment: Are you running ads on your site?

Comment: What is your website or some code please? Otherwise it is not possible to help you.

Comment: @putvande I edited my message and added the web site link.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. No problems or errors.

Comment: @putvande yes, it's work for me too. But some PCs give an error like this. It's look like plugins problem.

Comment: Which page is giving you an error?  I don't see that alert (it normally pops up as an alert box when I see that particular error).

Comment: @SeanKendle I don't know which but some plugins use this file. So if it's not on your FTP you should got that error too. It's ridiculous.

Comment: @SeanKendle meahwhile error fired up on index.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have Flash, remove this line:

```
<script src="js/AC_RunActiveContent.js"></script>
```

The file is not found anyway, and you don't need it...

Comment: Ah yes, I forget to remove it. I put the `AC_RunActiveContent.js` file into FTP root directory and it works properly.

Comment: You said you don't have flash on the site, and I don't know of a plugin that needs flash... which one do you suspect needs that file?  If you don't have flash, you don't need AC_RunActiveContent.js.

Comment: If I helped you solve this problem, can you please accept my answer and up-vote?